# How to configure ruby Neo4j ActiveRel object to get cascading persistance

Tags: ruby, neo4j

I experiment with Neo4j gem for working with Neo4j library. When you configure active nodes without using active relationships you can specify :origin property and on node.save it cascades through all graph saving everything auto-magically. Now I want to use active relationships to have some data on them and :origin is not allowed anymore on node relationship declaration and on node.save it doesn't propagate changes anymore.

Is there a way to achieve 'single node.save call - store all graph' functionality?

My problem is that the performance went down when I have to create each relationship separately, so maybe there is another way to batch the queries?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An example of your model (or a representation) would be helpful, but you should still be able to use `origin`.  The association on side of the relationship would have either a `type` option (if you aren't using `ActiveRel`) or a `rel_class` option (if you are).  The other side would have the `origin` option which allows you to not specify the `type`/`rel_class` a second time.

I'm not as clear on what you mean about cascading.  If you're using the latest version of the gem (6.1.10 currently) it should allow you to do things like `Model.new(association_name: association_id_or_object)` or `Model.create(association_name: association_id_or_object)`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that I don't have to specify rel_class on both ends. My point was that with  marking relations with origin I could  instantiate objects without persisting them, build a graph, and then after the graph was built I was calling save on a single main node and by following origins it was persisting all related nodes.

Comment: The problem was in a different place I guess - I didn't open transaction manually before building the graph and then on each node.create method new transaction was created and commited, which was time heavy. Now I manually start a transaction and it is being reused and it's much better.

Comment: Ah, excellent! ;)  I actually help maintain the gem but I've never thought to do that before.  Nice!